# Collecting a set of has_one associations in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-one, rails-geocoder

I have a model, `Offer`. Each `Offer` has_one `Location`. I'm trying to use the `Geocoder` gem method `near` to get all nearby `Location`s. The method is used like this:

```
@nearby_locations = Location.near(address, 100, :order => :distance)
```

I'm not sure how to replace `Location`, in `Location.near()`, with each `Offer`'s associated location. I can access each `Offer` object's location with `@first_offer.location`, but the `near` method is called on the entire `Location` table. How can I collect all the `Offer.location`s into an array so that I can use this method on them?

Thanks in advance. I hope I made sense. If not, just leave a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that I fully understand your question but I'll answer it as best I can. `offer.location` returns a collection of location objects so you can iterate over these objects and call the `near` method on each of them:

```
offer.location.each do |location|
  location.near
end
```

However, I don't think this will work with the `near` method because it acts as a class level scope. It is not designed to work on an individual record.

The Geocoder gem does provide other methods that you can use on individual records, for example `distance_from`. So you could do something like:

```
offer.location.each do |location|
  location.distance_from([40.714,-100.234])
end
```

Checkout the [Geocoder docs](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) for other available method calls.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll just look for other methods as you suggested.